# MSW (mock service worker) is not setting the body in mocked server response

Tags: node.js, next.js, msw

I am trying to test a request handler that returns a stream with [MSW](https://mswjs.io/), however, when testing, [MSW](https://mswjs.io/) does not appear to be setting the response body as expected. Here is an example of my code

```
// example of request method
const apiRequest = async (route) => {
    const response = await fetch(route, {
      cache: 'no-cache',
      method: 'post',
    });
    return { stream: response.body };
  };

// example of test
import { rest } from 'msw';
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';

const server = setupServer([]);

it('returns stream in the response', async () => {
    const url = '/mockUrl';
    const encoder = new TextEncoder();
    const data = encoder.encode('this is mocking a stream').buffer;

    server.use(rest.post(url, (req, res, ctx) => res(
      ctx.status(HttpStatus.OKAY),
      ctx.set(Headers.ContentLength, data.byteLength.toString()),
      ctx.set(Headers.ContentType, ContentType.Stream),
      ctx.body(data),
    )));
    await expect(apiRequest(route)).resolves.toStrictEqual({ stream: data });
  });
```

Whenever I run this test it fails because the body of the response is undefined and so the stream property returned by the handler is undefined. Reading through [the documentation](https://mswjs.io/docs/recipes/binary-response-type) it appears the `ctx.body()` method should be setting the body, but it is not. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong or if it is some kind of bug in [MSW](https://mswjs.io/). Any help would be appreciated! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem, I had called one of the functions (`response.json()`) that consumed the stream before returning it which then set the body to undefined. This was removed when simplifying my example, I didn't realize that's how it worked until I tried calling another function (`response.text()`) and got an error that illuminated the problem.